# How to determine the lag.max length for daily (10 years) data stock prices data set in R

Tags: time-series, arima, garch, copula, acf-pacf

I have 20 years of daily data set for some stock prices. I would like to investigate the autocorrelation for this using `acf` plot and `Ljung-Box` test. However, I wonder how to set the `lag.max` that required by the test. For example,

```
Box.test(mydata, lag = 5, type = "Ljung-Box")
```

Comment: I think these are two rather different questions and thus should be asked separately.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thanks. I will delete one of them.